# Nested/Chained parLapply functions (R)

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm unable to find a conclusive answer to whether I am able to use the output of one parLapply call immediately in another parLapply function. For example:

```
first.vars <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
second.vars <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)

no.cores <- detectCores() -1
cl <- makeCluster(no.cores)
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(parallel))
clusterExport(cl, ls())

parLapply(cl, first.vars, function(first.vars) parLapply(cl, second.vars,  function(second.vars) paste(c(first.vars, second.vars), collapse = ""))
```

My expectation would be that I retrieve a nested list with "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "B1", "B2" etc... Which is the case when I use a non-parallelised function.

However the parallel method simply doesn't work and my guess is that the 'cl' of the top-most parLapply doesn't contain the output of the bottom parLapply and therefore can't run.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would generally not advise to have multiple levels of parallelising if you can help it. what advantage would there be doing par twice?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how paralellisation works? Is it not possible to parallelise twice? i.e. code can't be sped up in this way?